# Can't Access object inside array in php blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

[image: Database]I am doing a query and returning a json to a Laravel client, I am trying to access each iteration with a foreach but when I am trying to access the informatoin this error occurs:

Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

I tried many methods and I don't know.

```
PHP FILE
public function indexJugetesDias(){
    $preguntas = $this::listarPreguntasHoy(1,10);




    return view('preguntasRespuestas')->with('preguntas', json_decode($preguntas, true));
}




public static function listarPreguntasHoy($pagina=1, $cantidad=10){


    if($cantidad<=0){
        $cantidad=10;
            }

            if($pagina<1){
                $pagina=1;
            }
        $pagina--;
$saltar = $pagina*10;


$preguntas = Question::select('questions.id', 'questions.id_user', DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(questions.date, '%Y-%m-%d')"), 'questions.title', 'questions.description', 'users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name')
->join('users', 'users.id', 'questions.id_user')
->whereRaw("DATE(questions.date) = CURDATE()")
->get()
->skip($saltar)
->take($cantidad)
->toJson();


return $preguntas;


}
```

```
PHP BLADE FILE
   @foreach ((array)$preguntas   as  $pregunta)
                                {{$pregunta->id}}
                            <li class="thread"><span class="time">Apr 21</span><span class="title">aaa </span><span class="icon"> <a class="subscribe" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></a><a class="flag" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></span></li>

                              @endforeach
```

```
HOW THE JSON LOOKS
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#359 (7) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["id_user"]=>
    int(1)
    ["DATE_FORMAT(questions.date, '%Y-%m-%d')"]=>
    string(10) "2020-05-01"
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) "Pregunta 1/05"
    ["description"]=>
    string(19) "Prueba Descripción"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(6) "Pinazo"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(4) "Guna"
  }
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Use `$pregunta['id']` instead.

Comment: It works! but I don't understand why the Id of the question is "5" but when I show it is "1". Is the fifth question I created

Comment: No idea mate, but that sounds like you need to do some debugging.

Comment: Your json doesn’t have an id values it says int(1) which means it’s an integer of 1 length. Same same with string(10). It’s a string of 10 length.

Comment: I don't know what can I do, I added another question and has the same id.

Comment: It’s clearly an issue with your database query then. Break the query down step by step or reduce it until you can figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting `$preguntas` as an `(array)` in `(array)$preguntas` which is not an object, therefore the error.

You can either call in your Blade:

```
{{ $pregunta['id'] }}
```

Or send the `$preguntas` as a Collection from your Controller by change your code to:

```
$preguntas = Question::select('questions.id', 'questions.id_user', DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(questions.date, '%Y-%m-%d')"), 'questions.title', 'questions.description', 'users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', 'questions.id_user')
    ->whereRaw("DATE(questions.date) = CURDATE()")
    ->skip($saltar)
    ->take($cantidad)
    ->get();
```